# Git flow release tag

Tags: git, git-flow, git-tag

I started using git flow to manage code for a medium sized project at work, I used the default for branches names and tag. I would like to know if it is possible to change the tag prefix, I have already look for a bit on google but all answers are related to the branches names not the releases tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `gitflow.prefix.versiontag` to set it.

For example to prefix with v, just use

```
git config gitflow.prefix.versiontag v
```